# What's so great about Block Selection Mode?

Tags: eclipse, editor, text-editor

Longtime Eclipse user here; I recently discovered the "Block Selection Mode" (Alt-Shift-A) that was added into Eclipse 3.5.   I tried it out, it's pretty neat--I can select a rectangle of text in my source code instead of selecting things a line at a time like I usually do.

Apparently this feature is common in other editors too, under other names like "column edit mode", etc.  A lot of people seem to really love it, but I've got by without for a long time.

**So my question is:  What kinds of things is this feature useful for?**

The only one I can think of is inserting a comment characters (like // or #) in front of a chunk of text.  Also, I supposed if I had a bunch of variables names that were all lined up and I wanted to change the first characters for all of them at once.   But surely there's more to it than that?  I mean, when it comes to choosing an editor, this feature is apparently a deal-breaker for some people!

Comment: +1 I've used it for the possible use cases you mention, but now that you ask...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it is *very* useful when working with fixed-position field data files, and you only want to select a few fields for search-replace or copy-paste. It is also good for things like this:

```
call_foo('A',123);
call_foo('B',143);
call_foo('C',331);
call_foo('A',113);
call_foo('R',789);
```

The code is all the same except for some characters in some columns. You could select a block around the second parameter and search for the line containing `113`. Useful when you have more than just a few lines all together in this format.

Comment: Not to mention, select ''_f' and change it to 'F' in a heartbeat.  Though in general I think it's much less useful in Eclipse than in a plain text editor.  Coding Java in Eclipse you'd just refactor the method name.  But when I code in Perl for example, I use UltraEdit, and the column editing saves me a ton of time.

Comment: Ah yes good point.  I do Java and Python in Eclipse, and I can see what you mean--it would be handier in Python where the refactoring tools aren't as fully developed yet.

Answer (score 3):

A colleague of mine told me of a project where they wrote JDBC code like this:

```
String query =
    "select question, answer, accepted " +
    "from so_answers                   " +
    "where poster = 'Jon Skeet'        " +
    "order by upvotes                  ";
```

So that they could block-select the SQL in order to paste it into a database tool and run it by hand. Seems a bit barmy to me, but it evidently worked for them.

Comment: Maybe they should try SquirrelSQL, which can add and remove Java style quoting to/from statements.

Answer (score 3):

If you arn't using a block cut/copy/paste operation at least four or five times a day then I would suggest you're just doing a lot of extra typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a file with fixed width fields, sometimes you only want to select one column.